# Customize PayPal Order Summary

Tags: paypal

I'm currently using PayPal express checkout with PHP, and after redirect to the payment page the order summary looks like this:

http://snag.gy/GsreY.jpg

Is there a way to change "Item number" and "Item price" to something else like "Reservation number" and "Reservation price"? If not is there a way to hide it from the order summary? Because when I first looked at it I thought the order quantity was 5 and I don't want my customers to be confused when it goes live.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to add order item params to your SetExpressCheckout request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the term "item number" and "item name" is fixed and neither is able to be customized. To hide them, please pass total amount only via parameter PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT, and remove the details like PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT, L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0, L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0 ... in SetExpressCheckout API.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/